# why my #3 menu is not showing at all everytime i execute or enter #3 menu

Tags: java

I'm having some problems in my output code. My #3 menu is not showing at all when I run it. only #1 and #2 menu. When I enter #3 it shows my #2 menu.

Note: #2 menu same coding as #1 menu

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    int foods = 1, drinks = 2, dessert = 3;


    double sw = 10.00;
    double bg = 15.00;
    double rm = 25.00;
    double it = 20.00;
    double ck = 15.00;
    double cf = 13.00;
    double brn = 10.00;
    double dnt = 15.00;
    double payment, change;



    System.out.println(" ******* Menu ******* ");
    System.out.println("[1]Food [2]Drinks [3]Desserts");
    System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");
    foods=Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine());
    if (foods == 1) {

        String choice1;
        System.out.println(" [a] Sandwich - 10.00 \n [b] Burger - 15.00 \n [c] Rice Meal - 25.00");
        System.out.println("\n Enter Choice: ");
        System.out.flush();
        choice1 = br.readLine();;
        if (choice1.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("You Chose a, Sandwich (10.00)");
            System.out.println("Enter Payment: ");
            payment=Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
           if (payment < 10) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");
           }else{
                change = payment - sw;
           System.out.println("Your Change is: "+change);
           System.out.println("Thank You!");
           }
        }
        else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
           System.out.println("You Chose e, Burger (15.00)"); 
           System.out.println("Enter Payment: ");
           payment=Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
           if (payment < 15) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");
           }else{
               change = payment - bg;
           System.out.println("Your Change is: "+change);
           System.out.println("Thank You!");
           }
        } 
        else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
           System.out.println("You Chose c, Rice Meal (25.00)"); 
           System.out.println("Enter Payment: ");
           payment=Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
           if (payment < 13) {
              System.out.println("Insufficient Funds"); 
           }else{
               change = payment - rm;
           System.out.println("Your Change is: "+change);
           System.out.println("Thank You!"); 
           }
        }     


    } else if(dessert == 3) {
        String choice3;
        System.out.println(" [g] brownies - 10.00 \n [h] donuts - 15.00");
        System.out.println("\n Enter Choice: ");
        System.out.flush();
        choice3 = br.readLine();
        if (choice3.equals("g")){
           System.out.println("You Chose g, brownies (10.00)"); 
           System.out.println("Enter Payment: ");
           payment=Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
           if(payment < 10) {
              System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");  
           }else{
               change = payment - brn;
           System.out.println("Your Change is: "+change);
           System.out.println("Thank You!");
           }
        }
    }  
}
```

Am I missing something here? I've been sitting around thinking something to compensate the program and finish it within 4 days.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "#3 menu"?  What is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output?  (and please update the question to include that info instead of just replying to my comment).

Comment: You're reading in a variable called `foods`. Then you're testing `if dessert == 3`, which is pointless. I think you mean `if foods == 3`. Also you're not even doing anything for the `drinks` menu so I guess you've missed that out, but if you're checking `if drinks==2`, then that condition is _always true_, so you won't ever get to your third menu.

Comment: #2 code is working same as coding in #1, my #3 is the problem should i put dessert=Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine()); too?